# Differencing Matrix/Coercion to Numeric in R

Tags: r

```
data=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(500*300,0,1),500,30))
weiner1=data.frame(cumsum(data))
```

Hi,

I am trying to take the difference of a matrix, so row-wise, I am trying to subtract element Matrix[m+1,n]-Matrix[m,n] but also have it such that the first row will be a set of NA's.

I tried the diff command:

```
diff(weiner1)
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

and

```
diff(as.numeric(weiner1)),dim(m)
Error in diff(as.numeric(weiner1), dim(m)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
apply(weiner1, 2, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
```

Comment: Bless your heart. Thx Akrun. I guess the reason the diff function wasn't working in the beginning was because you had to specify whether the first row/= will be the row with the NA's or the last row the one with NA's??

Comment: Or even, probably faster, `weiner1[-1, ] - weiner1[-nrow(weiner1), ]`? Actually not! `diff(as.matrix(weiner1))` seems the fastest

Comment: Not sure if I had to open another question for this. Let me know if I should. But could the apply function also be used to lag/lead the matrix? So I am trying to create a recursion where the values in row 2 in the matrix depend on the 1st row. The values in the 3rd row, depend on the 2nd and so forth. for example: Matrix(n)=1/Matrix(n-1)+Matrix(n-1)^2

Comment: `jessica`. Though your title suggested `matrix`, weiner1 was data.frame.  According to `?diff` documentation: `If ‘x’ is a matrix then the difference operations are carried out
     on each column separately.`.  You got a better answer from `Richard Scriven` using that option.  You can open another question after searching in the site for any similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `diff` without `apply`, as it operates on the columns of a matrix.

```
 rbind(NA, diff(as.matrix(weiner1)))
```

Comment: Perhaps rbind(NA, diff(as.matrix(weiner1))) would get the same result?

Comment: Many thanks.  I was wondering about that.